# onclick image change on BaseAdapter

Tags: android, baseadapter

I want to change imageview source (and music of course) from onclicklistener. It is changed, but first image changes on every click. How can i fix it?

This is my code:

```
public View getView(final int p, View v, ViewGroup arg2)
            {
                    Log.w("BaseAdapter", "p: "+p+", preP: "+preP );
                    
                    if (v == null)
                        v = li.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
                                            
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    TextView baslik = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    baslik.setText( isimler[p] );
                    
                    if ( p == preP )
                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
                    
                    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            if( preP != p  )
                            {
                                System.out.println("müzik çalışılacak.");
                                mPlay = MediaPlayer.create( getApplicationContext(), sarkilar[p] );
                                mPlay.start();
                                preP=p;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                mPlay.stop();
                                preP=-1;
                            }

                            //getView(p, v, arg2);
                            initList();                             
                        }
                    });

                    return v;
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a `onItemClickListener` on your `ListView` because this is the correct way to do it.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int pos,
                                long arg3) {
            Item i = (Item) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);

            mPlay = MediaPlayer.create( getApplicationContext(), sarkilar[pos] );
                            mPlay.start();
        }
    });
```

**OR**

If I had to modify your code

```
    v.setTag(p); //attach the position to your view
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //How you get the correct ImageView
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);

            //The position is attached to the Clicked view
            int position = (int) v.getTag(); 

            if( preP != position  )
            {
                System.out.println("müzik çalışılacak.");
                mPlay = MediaPlayer.create( getApplicationContext(), sarkilar[position] );
                mPlay.start();
                preP=position;
            }
            else
            {
                mPlay.stop();
                preP=-1;
            }

            //getView(p, v, arg2);
            initList();                             
        }
    });
```

But personally I would not use the second approach

Comment: Thanks Neil! Second solution is work! 

Im not understand how to change imageview source on your first solution.

Comment: The first one wouldn't be coded in your adapter but in the class you define the listview. Please accept as the answer! Glad I could help