# How to create a clickable Listview and go to new page

Tags: android, listview, clickable

I'm a new programmer in android. I want to create a Clickable Listview. I mean when users clicked on one item it goes to a new page and start a new activity. Please help me. 
Thanks in advance.
It's my code in mainactivity.java.

```
package first.app;

import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterViewFlipper;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.textView1, 
    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.games)));

}

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list,parent, false);
        String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.games);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        tv.setText(items[position]);

        if (items[position].equals("فوتبال")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.football);
        }
        else if (items[position].equals("شنا")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.swimming);
        }
        else if (items[position].equals("شمشیربازی")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.fencing);
        }
        else if (items[position].equals("شطرنج")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.chess);
        }       
        return row;
    }


    }


}
```

Comment: Look at this answer I posted. It should solve your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979592/onclick-image-change-on-baseadapter/16981787#16981787

Comment: put intent and load in next activity

Answer (score 1):

use Listview item click listener

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {    
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        // your code is here on item click
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView lv = getListView();


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
               String selval = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

              Intent intnt = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextactivity.class);
                intnt.putExtra("selval ", selval);
              startActivity(i);

          }
        });
```