# How to create a clickable listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am currently trying to create a clickable list view. I've created the xml file but confused on what to do after to make the items in the list clickable. Below is the xml code.

activities_clubs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:entries="@array/activities"
        android:padding="40dp" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the strings.xml file:

```
<string-array name="activities">
        <item >American Football</item>
        <item >Archery</item>
        <item >Athletics</item>
        <item >Badminton</item>
        <item >Basketball (Men)</item>
        <item >Basketball (Women)</item>
        <item >Dance</item>
        <item >Fencing</item>
        <item >Football (Men)</item>
</string-array>
```

What would i need to do next to make the items clickable?

Comment: I suggest you start studying some tutorials and follow some examples and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: There are many tutorials that will help you achieve this. You need to add an onItemClick() method to your java.

Comment: Follow these links ....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281197/android-how-to-create-clickable-listview


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038264/how-to-create-a-clickable-listview-and-go-to-new-page


 hope it  helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your java file, do something like this.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        // DO SOMETHING HERE
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this code

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("ListView", " position:" + position);
            // Then you start a new Activity via Intent
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this,ItemDetail.class);

            startActivity(intent);
```