# How can I search for in the list view

Tags: database, search, android-listview, onclick, custom-lists

I want to make a list view and a large number of names placed within it. When you click on any name, is a new activity and then go to that person's profile information to show us. And I also want to do a search field to make it easier.

Comment: will the listView support multi-line or single-line ?

Comment: will the listView support multi-line...

Comment: I asking you..you want the listView support multiple line or a single line? So I can provide you some example on this

Comment: Excuse me. I am weak in English. As I said, I am multi-line list view

Comment: Thank you Please submit your example

Answer (score 0):

This is the example on how to [Create a custom multi-line ListView bound to an ArrayList](http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx).

If you have zero-knowledge on android, you can just copy and paste the code, and see what are the output is.

In order to make the `listView` clickable and `intent` to another activity, you can write like this

```
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { // if listView is clicked
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Object o = listview.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(), Person_Profile.class);
                startActivityForResult(i,PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }
```

You may refer as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038264/how-to-create-a-clickable-listview-and-go-to-new-page) too .

Comment: thank you my friend. There is great. Thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 0):

You will find the best example here [Android Custom ListView Example with Images](http://www.android-development-tutorial.net/android-custom-listview-example-with-images/)

All you need to do is copy & paste the code in your project. You will be able to get awesome Custom ListView with images (thumbnail).

To create clickable ListView, Use **Intent** as mentioned by **John**. Hope this works fine for You..